# Coanda effect and Teapot effect

Tags: fluid-dynamics

According to many sources, the [teapot effect](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=teapot+effect) and the [Coanda effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) are the same phenomenon. 
But some sources claim these are two different effects. Does anyone know a reference where this issue is discussed?

Answer (score 3):

The [*teapot effect*](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/415946/the-death-of-the-teapot-effect/) is flow attachment of liquid to solid due to the solid's hydrophilic or hydrophobic property, the same thing that controls water beading.
This is different from what makes air follow a surface.

[*John S. Denker*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/spins.html#sec-coanda) has something to say about this:

> It appears that surface tension plays two very important roles:
>
> 1. At the water/air interface it prevents mixing of the air and water.
> 2. At
>      the water/wing interface it plays a dominant role in making the water
>      stick to the surface.
>
> In both respects this is quite unlike the
>   air-in-air jet, where the air/wing surface tension has no effect and
>   there is no such thing as air/air surface tension.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The teapot effect is the same as the lift of the wing. If we use low temperature air instead of water in the teapot, the teapot effect will also occur. Why does the teapot effect occur? Because the teapot outlet is a curved surface, when water flows out of the teapot outlet, there will be a low pressure on the surface, when the low pressure is not low enough, there will be a teapot effect; and when the low pressure is low enough, air will squeeze into the water and the teapot outlet under the action of atmospheric pressure, water will be separated from the teapot outlet. This separation is similar to the stall of the wing, the stall at the outlet of the teapot.

This is not exactly the same as the Caode effect.